# Change index array in PHP, laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have one array the same below has two dimension and also index 0 and 1 but i want to get new array with second one array.

My array:

```
array:2 [▼
      0 => array:1 [▼
        "fileupload[0]" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#313 ▶}
      ]
      1 => array:1 [▼
        "fileupload[1]" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#317 ▶}
      ]
    ]
```

My Expected result like this:

```
array:2 [▼
    "fileupload[0]" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#313 ▶}
    "fileupload[1]" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#317 ▶}
]
```

so please share me the way i can get my expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use collection method collapse

```php
$flattenedArray = collect($myArray)->collapse()->all();
```

Comment: @Rajes Glad I could help. Pls remember to mark answer as accepted for the benefit of subsequent visitors.

Comment: while this answer is correct, I'd suggest that @Rajes also learns, how to do such a thing in plain php, as array handling is something fundamental

Comment: @kuh-chan sorry bother i am new in php and also less experience with array

Answer (score -1):

You are creating the array incorrectly. The index 0 and 1 are creating by default because you are not defining the indexes of your array.

So what you need to do is define the indexes of your array, like this:

```
$array = [
    "fileupload[0]" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#313 ▶}
    "fileupload[1]" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#317 ▶}
];
```

What you should not do:

```
$array = [
    // Will create the 0 index by default
    [
        "fileupload[0]" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#313 ▶}
    ]

    // Will create the 1 index by default
    [
        "fileupload[1]" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#317 ▶}
    ]
];
```